# How to Send a list of checkbox value?

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox, javabeans

in my jsp pageIi print the users in table , and the admin can select many users to delete

I print them like that

```
 while (iter.hasNext()){

     element =(Etudinat) iter.next(); 
    %>
  <tr>  
    <th scope="row"><%=element.getUserName() %></th>
<td><%=element.getNom() %></td>
<td><%=element.getPrenom() %></td>
<td><%=element.getSexe() %></td>
<td><%=element.getEmail() %></td>
<td><%=element.getIDFilliere() %></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Supp" value="<%=element.getUserName() %>"> <br></td>
</tr>
 <% } %>
```

How can i send the values of the inputs Supp ??

I want to send them with a form & javaBean if thats possible, how can I regroupe them on a list !!

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the checkboxes inside a form, and add a submit button in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="the/path/to/your/action">
    the existing code containing your chackboxes

    <input type="submit" value="Delete checked users"/>
</form>
```

Besides:

1. It's probably time to rename your "Etudinat" class into "Etudiant", before it gets referenced everywhere.
2. Using scriptlets in JSPs is bad practice for years. Use an MVC framework like Stripes or Spring MVC, use JSP EL, the JSTL and tags. The MVC framework will take care of mapping form inputs to JavaBean properties, and this is precisely what you want to do.
3. Always escape strings when you're not absolutely sure they can't contain HTML special chars. If some student fills its email address field with `<script>while (true) {alert("You're an asshole");}</script`>, your boss won't be happy.